# Save variable using fwrite

Tags: php, fwrite

I just trying to understand how to use fwrite. In the below code, i am trying to save the output in the text file. I am just getting an empty txt file.
Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong here

```
<?php
    $name =  fix_name("ALAN", "james", "LiM");
    echo $name[0] . " " . $name[1] . " " . $name[2];
    function fix_name($n1, $n2, $n3) {
        $n1 = ucfirst(strtolower($n1));
        $n2 = ucfirst(strtolower($n2));
        $n3 = ucfirst(strtolower($n3));

        return array($n1, $n2, $n3);

}
    $fp = fopen("name.txt", "wb");
    $written = fwrite($fp, $name);
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: You cannot write arrays to a file. You need to use `serialize()` if you want to save an array. Don't forget to `unserialize()` it after reading the file. You may want to use PHP5's file reading and writing function. `file_get_contents()` `file_put_contents()`

Comment: Thank you. I will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an `array` to `fwrite`.
If you enable error reporting with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You would get a warning saying

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in file.php on line 16

Either return a string from your function

```
return $n1 . ', ' . $n2 . ', ' . $n3;
```

Or outside the function, use `implode` to get a string from the elements of the array

```
$name = implode(', ',fix_name("ALAN", "james", "LiM"));
```

Also, outside the function, print out just the `$name` variable

```
print $name;
```

In your text file you will have this

```
Alan, James, Lim
```